# Cannot change string to specific message using multiple else ifs - Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I am attempting to change the error message displayed in a login screen depending on what is actually wrong with the form.

For example,

Missing component | Error message

Password | 'Password missing'

Username| 'Username missing'

Both | 'Credentials missing'

however I cannot seem to get all of the messages to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you compare the values to `undefined`.

Instead, rely on falsy/truthy values :

```
  if (!formUser && !formPass) {
    this.errorMessage = 'Log in credentials are missing';
  } else if (formUser && !formPass) {
    this.errorMessage = 'password missing';
  } else if (!formUser && formPass) {
    this.errorMessage = 'username missing';
  }
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-message-changing-pdd7ep?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[What is truthy / falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: Amazing! I forget about that side of JS sometimes. - Will accept in 7mins when I can

Comment: That's also the main reason of its criticism, I'm glad someone finds this amazing too :D Good luck with your project !